# does anyone know how to do a revolution in solidworks using python?

Tags: python, solidworks

It happens that I have a sketch to which I want to make a revolution, I have already defined the revolution, but I don't know how to select the axis on which it should rotate

```
 # make a new sketch on the Front Plane
        self.select_by_id2("Front Plane", "PLANE")
        self.insert_sketch()
        # sketch and dimension main tab shape
        self.create_line_vertical(self.height)
        self.create_line_horizontal(self.length, self.height)
        self.create_line_vertical1(self.length, self.height, self.height1)
        self.create_line_horizontal1(self.length, self.length1, self.height1)
        self.create_line_vertical2(self.length1, self.height1, self.height2)
        self.create_line_horizontal2(self.length1, self.length2, self.height2)
        self.create_line_vertical3(self.length2, self.height2)
        self.create_line_horizontal3(self.length2)
        self.select_by_id2("Line1", "SKETCHSEGMENT")
        self.add_dimension()
        # Revolve 360°
        self.select_by_id2("Sketch1", "SKETCH")
        self.select_by_id2("Line1", "AXIS")
        self.revolve_shaft()


def revolve_shaft(self):

        featureMgr.FeatureRevolve2(True, True, False, False, False, False,
                                   0, 0, 6.28318530718, 0, False, False,
                                   0.01, 0.01, 0, 0, 0, True, True, True)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [FeatureRevolve2 Documentation](http://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks%7Esolidworks.interop.sldworks.ifeaturemanager%7Efeaturerevolve2.html), you need to select the sketch with Mark 0, and Mark 16 for the Axis.

In your case, it should be something like:

```
self.SelectByID2("Sketch1", "SKETCH", 0, 0, 0, False, 0, Nothing, swSelectOptionDefault)    
self.SelectByID2("Axis1", "AXIS", 0, 0, 0, True, 16, Nothing, swSelectOptionDefault)
```